# How can I make Kaplan-Meier Survival curve with 3 Plots

Tags: r, bioinformatics, survival-analysis, survival

[image]

I am currently learning how to do Kaplan-Meier survival curves.
I'm using TCGA-LIHC cohort to visualize survival curves with 3 subtypes (strata) which are classified by 2 genes (PTPRC, FOXP3).
for now, I can make survival curves individually, but I don't know how to code 3 plots on R, like making groups subtype1 for PTPRC high FOXP3 low and so on.
I added an example image for my question. I hope someone else could help me.

I'm thinking bout grouping them by median values (high for higher than median value, low for lower than median value) and subtype3 will be PTPRC low.
when the grouping is done, maybe I could handle the clinical data which are with it.

Comment: Please include a [MRE] including some sample data as text, not images, and the code you have tried. SO is a forum for programming questions. If you don't have any code yet and you don't know how to get started, [Bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

library(survival)
library(ggplot2)

## Load the data

data(tcga_lihc)

## Create the Kaplan-Meier survival objects

subtype1 <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ PTPRC, data=tcga_lihc)
subtype2 <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ FOXP3, data=tcga_lihc)
subtype3 <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data=tcga_lihc)

## Plot the survival curves

ggplot() +
geom_step(data=subtype1, aes(x=time, y=surv, color="PTPRC high")) +
geom_step(data=subtype2, aes(x=time, y=surv, color="FOXP3 low")) +
geom_step(data=subtype3, aes(x=time, y=surv, color="PTPRC low")) +
scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "black")) +
labs(x="Time (days)", y="Survival probability")